# Unable to print an array of character in java? Possibly encoded?

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding, char

I wanted to start a little project today, but I encountered a weird (at least for me) bug.
Given an array of characters, I cannot print these numbers using for loops.

Here is the code.

```
public class Grid
{
    public static char[][] matrix = {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4, 5, 6},
            {7, 8, 9}
    };

    public static void draw()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Main class

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Grid.draw();
    }
}
```

The output

I don't understand what the problem is, because if I switch from "char[][]" to "int[][]" everything works normally?
The code looks normal to me, can anyone explain how to fix this? And the reason why this is happening?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing here is that `char` type in Java is a 2-byte *integral number* type. So, you are able to assign *numbers* to a `char` variable. But codepoint for character '1' is not equal to a number 1.

I suppose the example will work as expected if you initialize a character array as follows:

```
    public static char[][] matrix = {
            {'1', '2', '3'},
            {'4', '5', '6'},
            {'7', '8', '9'}
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Character Array must be initialized using single quotes('') and that's the only reason you are able to use `int[]` but getting an error in `char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your characters in single quotes. '1','2'....

Answer (score 0):

Your array is a 2D `char` array. That means everything inside it is a `char`. When you `System.out.println((char) 1);`, it will print the ASCII character "with id" equal to 1, and who knows what is this character (for me it prints a character which my browser cannot show). In order to see it better, do `System.out.println((char) 65);`. You will see that the output is `'A'`, because in ASCII, 'A' is the 65 character.

If you want to print 1, 2,3 etc, you will have either to add a single quote (let java that they are characters) to each cell value of this array, which means that when you will print, it will do `System.out.println('1');`. Or you will give the ASCII code. For 1, it is 49. So `System.out.println((char) 49);` will print 1.